# 選択したcellの一つ前のcellの中身を取得したい

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

cellectionviewで一つ前のcellの中身が取得したいのですがなかなかうまくいきません。
どのようにすればうまくいくでしょうか。

今、cell.textLabel.textで1から順番に数字が入っているだけです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collectionview`のデータソースクラス（のインスタンス）を`CollectionViewDelegate`でもあるように記述し、該当する`collectionView`インスタンスの`delegate`にそのインスタンスを設定して、そのクラスに、

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, shouldSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) -> Set<IndexPath>`

を実装し、この関数の中で`indexPaths`に入っている値が選択されたItemのインデックス（群）なので、その一つ前のデータソースを参照すれば良いと思います。

つまり、

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, shouldSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) -> Set<IndexPath> {
    for index: IndexPath in indexPathes {
        let before: Integer = index.item - 1
        // beforeに代入された値を使って、一つ前のデータソースを取り出し、それに対する処理を行う
    }// end foreach indexPathes
}// end func collectionView shouldSelectItemsAt indexPaths
```

の様なメソッドで、//の部分に選択されたセルの一つ前のセルに対する処理を行えば良いのではないでしょうか

Comment: indexPath.rowを-1してそのあとindexPath.rowに戻すことはできますか？

Comment: 上記回答のコーディング例を追記してみました。`indexPath.raw`や`indexPath.item`を変更するのではなく、その値から1を引いた変数を作り、それを介して処理をおこなえば・・・という考え方です